# Firebase Dynamic link social info

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

Faced a problem. I need to get meta information from a dynamic link. To display a preview inside my application.

What I do:

I am generate a link with social data:

```
const param = {
            link: config.websiteLink,
            domainUriPrefix: 'https://mysite.page.link',
            android: this._androidConfig,
            ios: this._iosConfig,
            social: {
                title: 'SOME TITLE',
                descriptionText: 'SOME DESCRIPTION,
                imageUrl: 'SOME IMAGE'
            navigation: {
                forcedRedirectEnabled: true,
            }
        }

const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(param, 'SHORT');
```

Result:
**https://mysite.page.link/TSFxds (not real link)**

I need some logic for get this social info from 'result' link.
I trying to use **fetch(link)**, but this function returns only web page without any social tags and info from link configuration.

Looks like reverse engineering for firebase dynamic link =)